# Java program monitor files opened and closed in 3rd party application

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to constantly monitor when a file is opened in a particular 3rd party program that I don't have code for (Microsoft Word for example), the name of the particular file opened, and when that file/program is closed.

The purpose behind knowing this information is so that I can keep track of how long certain "documents" or files are opened to easily log hours on various projects.

Right now, the only way I can think of in order to accomplish this is to have my Java program be the one sending the commands to open particular files and then making note of when those files are closed, but I'd prefer this to run more in the background and be as easy and transparent as possible for the user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check whether a file is open at a given time. Check this periodically, and when the status changes, the file was either opened or closed.

```
try {
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    // file is closed
} catch(IOException e) {
    // file is open
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. So as I figured, it's probably impossible to target the 3rd party application, but instead target the files that could be opened. In order to get an accurate time that each file is opened, I would need to run this scan quite a bit. Would it be light on the resources?

Comment: Depends on how accurate you want the timestamp to be. If you only need to know within the hour, yeah, it'd be extremely light. If you want to know within a hundredth of a second, not light at all. You probably want somewhere in between.

Comment: Right. Down to the hundredth of a second is probably overkill, but within a minute or two would be preferable. I'll give it a shot and see how light it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
/  TO CHECK WHETHER A FILE IS OPENED 
    //  OR NOT (not for .txt files)

    //  the file we want to check
    String fileName = "C:\\Text.xlsx";
    File file = new File(fileName);

    // try to rename the file with the same name
    File sameFileName = new File(fileName);

    if(file.renameTo(sameFileName)){
        // if the file is renamed
        System.out.println("file is closed");    
    }else{
        // if the file didnt accept the renaming operation
        System.out.println("file is opened");
    }
```